# Setting the text of an NSTextField programmatically

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder

I have a GUI built on IB (Xcode 4).
It has a Static Text field connected to an NSTextField. After reading the information from an XML file it's supposed to change the text to whatever it is coming from the XML

the .h is as follow:

```
IBOutlet NSTextField * DataBaseLocation;
```

the .m

```
NSMutableArray* DBLoc = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSXMLElement* root  = [doc rootElement];
NSArray* DBarray = [root nodesForXPath:@"//DataBaseLocation" error:nil];
for(NSXMLElement* xmlElement in DBarray)
    [DBLoc addObject:[xmlElement stringValue]];

NSString * DBLocationString = [DBLoc objectAtIndex:0];
[DataBaseLocation setStringValue:DBLocationString];

NSLog(@"DBLoc: %@", DBLoc);
```

The `NSLog` shows that `DBLoc` has the correct string, yet the Text Field is empty and never gets set.

yes, I checked the connections in IB.
Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

I needed to initialize the `NSXMLDocument` with `NSXMLDocumentTidyXML` like:

```
NSXMLDocument* doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:input] options:NSXMLDocumentTidyXML error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should print out DBLocationString instead of DBLoc to make sure it's not empty or in some corrupted format that can't be passed as a string value and go from there.

Comment: If the string is ok, then there must be something wrong with your connections or declaration as the code you have should be working perfectly for setting the text field.  Sorry I couldn't help more, it's hard to know for sure without being able to fiddle with the project some.