# OSX - cannot set an NSTextField with a string from an NSTimer

Tags: macos, nstextfield

I cannot seem to set a timer output to an NSTextField. I've looked at this [Q/A,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862848/setting-the-text-of-an-nstextfield-programmatically) among many, but must be doing something different but wrong.

I initialize the timer and the textfield in WindowDidLoad.

My timer method is as follows:

```
time += 1;
        if((time % 60) <= 9) {
            NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:0%d",(time/60),(time%60)];
            [timerTextField setStringValue:tempString];
        } else {
            NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d",(time/60),(time%60)];
            timerTextField.stringValue = tempString;
        }
        NSLog(@"timerTextField: %@", timerTextField.stringValue);
```

As you can see, I log the textfield output.
I have an IBOutlet connection from the the File's owner to the timerTextField.

I can see the output correctly in the log, but the textfield string is not populated.

Can anyone see anything I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted looks OK to me. (You could replace it by binding your `timerTextField` to the time value via Cocoa Bindings though).

How did you create your timer and to which runloop(mode) did you add it?
Another problem could be that the outlet to your `timerTextField` is not connected. Can you set a breakpoint in your timer selector and check if `timerTextField` is not nil.

**Update:**

I just tried your code and for me it works.
Given that you have an IBOutlet named timerTextField connected to a NSTextField instance in Interface Builder, this code updates the textfield each second:

```
@interface SSWAppDelegate ()
{
    NSUInteger time;
}

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *timerTextField;

@end

@implementation SSWAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)updateTime:(id)sender
{
    time += 1;
    if((time % 60) <= 9) {
        NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu:0%lu",(time/60),(time%60)];
        [self.timerTextField setStringValue:tempString];
    } else {
        NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu:%lu",(time/60),(time%60)];
        self.timerTextField.stringValue = tempString;
    }
    NSLog(@"timerTextField: %@", self.timerTextField.stringValue);
}

@end
```

Comment: I should have added the initial timer create.. Here it is: myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeChanged:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; I do log the timerTextField, and I can see that the timer is working. I also checked the outlet. I like your idea of binding. I will try that now.. Will let you know.. Thanks very much for your thoughtful answer..

Comment: hmm. I tried binding - the value of timerTextField to the Window Controller. Still no luck. If you have any other thoughts, please let me know. I haven't tried setting a breakpoint yet.

Comment: I added a breakpoint, and it shows that - using my code above, the tempString is populated correctly, but the textField.stringValue is not.. I guess that is progress ... I know I'm initializing the textField. Anyway, you've pointed me in the right direction, so thanks again..

Comment: I updated my original answer. Can you try to copy & paste the above code. If you connect the timerTextField in Interface Builder, it should work as expected.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you ever so much. I just ran it in a little test app, and it's perfect. I see the differences in the code. Something learned!